# Set default font-family in jWYSIWYG

Tags: jquery, css, font-family, jwysiwyg

I set the font-family in the jquery.jwysiwyg.js (line-# 497 where < body > is defined) and added a CSS …

```
$('#wysiwyg').wysiwyg({css : { fontFamily: 'Arial, Tahoma', fontSize : '12px', color : '#333333'}});
```

The textarea shows Arial as font-family but when I click the remove formatting button it turns to Times New Roman.
Is there any way I can set a default font to prevent this? I don't want Times as a base font.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `jwysiwyg` renders in an `iframe`, the styles of the containing page will not render (as it is actually a separate HTML file) and so `jwysiwyg` will default to the standard font for the browser, which is usually Times New Roman.

You can use an external stylesheet to counter this issue like so:

```
$('#wysiwyg').wysiwyg({
    css: 'editor.css'
});
```

And within `editor.css` you would put `body { font-family: "Arial, Tahoma"; }`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. When I apply the font via a css file it's the same thing. When I delete the formatting it shows Times New Roman.

Here I removed formatting from Ipsum …

`<p><span style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51); font-family: Arial, Tahoma; font-size: 12px; ">Lorem </span>Ipsum<font color="#333333" face="Arial, Tahoma"><span style="font-size: 12px;"> Dolor Sit Amet</span></font></p><p style="font-family: Arial; "></p>`

Comment: Sorry … sorry. My fault. Didn't set the path to editor.css correctly. Relative path hasn't worked but an absolute path did the work :-)

Thanks!!

Comment: @suntrop Sure. Be sure to accept the answer if it worked for you.

Comment: FWIW, I just ran into this same question and found that relative paths do work, but you must specify a location relative to the web page location, not the script location.

Comment: in your new css you should write: body.wysiwyg (notice the class) in order to apply only to the editor

Answer (score 0):

Use arial black or arial narrow, for example:

```
font_formats: "Andale Mono=andale mono,times;"+
        "Arial=arial narrow,avant garde;"+
        "Arial Black=arial black,avant garde;"+
        "Courier New=courier new,courier;"+
        "Georgia=georgia,palatino;"+
        "Impact=impact,chicago;"+
        "Symbol=symbol;"+
        "Tahoma=tahoma,arial,helvetica,sans-serif;"+
        "Times New Roman=times new roman,times;"+
        "Verdana=verdana,geneva;"+
        "Webdings=webdings;"+
        "Wingdings=wingdings,zapf dingbats",
```